# How do I change the index value for the last row of a dataframe in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe shown below.  How do I change the value of the index in the last row from 2022-12-31 to 2023-12-31. Essentially what I want is something like this index value of last row == index value of second last row + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)

```
                 FGE       FFI       FRA    FARCAD    FCOCAD      CASH   SafeCap  SixtyForty
date                                                                                        
2020-12-31       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN         NaN
2021-12-31  0.137961 -0.040112  0.098811  0.062196  0.088000  0.006958  0.075419    0.121350
2022-12-31 -0.142319 -0.090379  0.068276  0.102470  0.095588  0.027641  0.034632   -0.102522
2022-12-31  0.038630 -0.035256  0.067030  0.044813  0.037752  0.044188  0.048536    0.021759
```

I tried this but I get an error "Index does not support mutable operations"

df.index[-1]=df.index[-2]+ pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign to an Index, one option is to use a temporary Series:

```
s = df.index.to_series()
s.iloc[-1] = s.iloc[-2] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)
df.index = s
```

Or use a list:

```
df.index = df.index[:-1].tolist()+[df.index[-2]+pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)]
```

Updated DataFrame:

```
                 FGE       FFI       FRA    FARCAD    FCOCAD      CASH   SafeCap  SixtyForty
date                                                                                        
2020-12-31       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN         NaN
2021-12-31  0.137961 -0.040112  0.098811  0.062196  0.088000  0.006958  0.075419    0.121350
2022-12-31 -0.142319 -0.090379  0.068276  0.102470  0.095588  0.027641  0.034632   -0.102522
2023-12-31  0.038630 -0.035256  0.067030  0.044813  0.037752  0.044188  0.048536    0.021759
```

Comment: Awesome, that works perfectly!  Thanks mozway!